# hive regexp_extract vertex failed due to own_task_failure

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to insert data into a table using regexp_extract() with the following code

```
insert overwrite table flightsdb.flight_delays_hw3 
select
regexp_extract(col_value,',^(?:([^,]*)\,?{2}',1)t1,
regexp_extract(col_value,',^(?:([^,]*)\,?{5}',1)t2,
regexp_extract(col_value,',^(?:([^,]*)\,?{19}',1)t3,
regexp_extract(col_value,',^(?:([^,]*)\,?{20}',1)t4,
regexp_extract(col_value,',^(?:([^,]*)\,?{21}',1)t5,
regexp_extract(col_value,',^(?:([^,]*)\,?{22}',1)t6,
regexp_extract(col_value,',^(?:([^,]*)\,?{23}',1)t7
from temp_table1;
```

But I kept getting the following error:

```
Vertex did not succeed due to OWN_TASK_FAILURE, failedTasks:1 killedTasks:3,
Vertex vertex_1586463911838_0026_1_00 [Map 1] killed/failed to:OWN_TASK_FAILURE]DAG 
did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:0
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Unclosed ( in the 1st non-matching group.

Comment: @leftjoin can you specify what do you mean by unclosed?

Comment: I mean it should be pair of parenthesis: (group bla bla). This goup (?: has no closing ')'.

Comment: What are you trying to extract?

Comment: @leftjoin I was trying to extract data from a table into another table. The data are comma separated text files and are stored in 1 column, and I was trying to use regexp_extract to extract it into different columns in another table

Comment: use split function: `split(col_value,',')[0] as col1`

Comment: ok thanks, I will try with that.